# How to access workspace api from Lightning Component embedded in Visualforce Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are using a Custom URL button to invoke a VisualForce Page in which a Lightning Component in embedded (We are doing this because Lightning Quick Action gives only a Modal Box and we need a bull blown page).

Since we are using Lightning Console Application, this Visualforce Page opens in a new Tab. While trying to redirect the User to the Record Page on click of Save, i am not able to close the current tab as the workspace api wouldnt work in Lightning Components embedded in VisualForce Pages.

We have already tried using sforce.console but that wouldnt work in lightning env.

Any help would be appreciated.